# Не выполняется php в html файлах

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, vesta

Я добавил в .htaccess запись AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm , однако php выполняется только в корне на главной странице index.html, при этом в index2.html, в корне сайта уже не выполняется, и соответственно в каталогах в html файлах php также не выполняется.
Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего такой эффект и как решить эту проблему на конкретном домене?
Я знаю, что многие уже задавали подобные вопросы, но различные вариации с файлом htaccess не решили мою проблему. На сервере установлена Ubuntu и панелька Vestacp.

Comment: А зачем вы используете PHP в HTML? Не проще сразу PHP, а в .htaccess выставить чтоб дописывал .html к URL?

Comment: Мне передали сайт с другого сервака, сайт состоит из множества html страниц, которые содержат php вставки. Менять расширения для всех html страниц займет не один день. Хотелось бы оставить все как есть.

Comment: Не надо вручную менять, запустите скрипт bash который переименует все файлы рекурсивно во всех подпапках. Иначе вам придётся добавлять это правило в конфигурирование сервера, а не как сейчас в каждую папку где есть HTML файлы.

Comment: На vestacp отключил Proxy Support NGINX для конкретного домена и проблема решилась, теперь php выполняется в html файлах.